# Django: admin chained filtering

Tags: django, filtering, admin, chained

I want to do a chained filtering but it does not work

```
def queryset(self, request):
   qs = super(MaterialAdmin, self).queryset(request)
   if request.user.is_superuser:
       self.exclude = []
       return qs
   else:
       self.exclude = ['droits_acces', 'groupe']


   ff = qs.filter(groupe= request.user)
   gg = qs.filter(user=request.user)

   jj = qs.filter(user=request.user).filter(groupe= request.user)

   return jj
```

How to do ?

ff = [CC409, ST54]

gg = [Al2O3, BB79, CC409]

I would like to have

jj = [CC409, ST54, Al2O3, BB79]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for complex queries.

```
from django.db.models import Q

...
    def queryset(self, request):
    ...
    return qs.filter(Q(groupe=request.user)|Q(user=request.user))
```

Comment: and if I want to view the materials of another user but with the same group ?

Comment: The `|` combines 2 `Q()` objects with an OR logic. So it combines the elements of the first Q and the second.